# Select tag to link to new page onChange within Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Building my first full stack rails app!

I'm attempting to create a select drop down that will navigate to a show page within my app. Each option is a college that has its own independent show page. I'm having trouble with creating the syntax around my onChange listener and route so that the user navigates to the correct show page.

```
<select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
      <option>Select A College/University</option>
    <% @schools.each do |school| %>
      <option><%= link_to school.name, school_path(school)%></option>
    <%end%>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links in `<option>` tags aren't valid.  You're probably just getting back the link text (i.e, school name) when you try to access the `option.value`.  What you need to do is make the link the value and the school name the text.

```
<% @schools.each do |school| %>
  <option value="<%= school_path(school) %>"><%= school.name %></option>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help with this one. Its been driving me nuts for about 3 hours. Final syntax:

Comment: <select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) 
    self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
      <option>Select A College/University</option>
        <% @schools.each do |school| %>
      <option value="<%= school_path(school) %>"><%= school.name %>
    </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use select_tag like below

```
<%= select_tag(:id, options_from_collection_for_select(@schools, "id", "name"), 
       :onchange => ("window.location.href = 'school/'+$(this).val();") %>
```